# Override standard knowledge article edit page with VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, knowledge

Did anyone tried to override edit page of knowledge article? Is it possible to do like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot override that page because you cannot also override the buttons in the  Article Management tab or knowledge tab. There is nothing stopping you from creating your own own edit/publish page which could be accessed from a different location but it wouldn't be user-friendly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Why i need edit page override with VF page is, there is a limit of 100 categories per category group I needed more than 300 articles so I thought of overriding edit page and instead of categories, custom picklist values. Is it feasible? please suggest a possible way to achieve my scenario.

Comment: I would look at re-evaluating the requirements. This not practical or user-friendly at all. If you go for the picklist option instead of using categories, you would lose features in the standard pages such as filtering content by category. I don't think you are utilizing categories correctly if you need so many.